# How to spyOn a method that is returned from another method from a different module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have 3 files in my project - a.js, utils.js, a.unit.spec.js. How do I mock a method in Jest (myFunc) from a.js which is a returned value from a method (helper) in utils.js (this is a third party lib)? I am getting this error -

> Cannot spy the myFunc property because it is not a function;
>   undefined given instead

a.js

```
import {helper} from 'utils.js'

export const myFunc = helper();

export const getData = () => {
    return myFunc()
        .then(...)
}
```

util.js (third party library)

```
export const helper = (promiseFunc, time) => (...args) => (
    Promise.race([
        promiseFunc(...args),
        new Promise((_, reject) =>
            setTimeout(() => {...}, time)
        ),
    ])
);
```

a.unit.spec.js

```
import * as a from './a';

describe('getData', () => {
    it('myFunc is called', () => {
        const myFuncMock = jest.spyOn(a, 'myFunc');
        a.getData().then(() => {})
        expect(myFuncMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
})
```

Comment: What does `helper` from `util.js` look like?

Comment: updated my question with util.js - also this is a 3rd party lib

Answer (score 0):

Here is the completed demo:

`a.ts`:

```js
import { helper } from './utils';

export const myFunc = helper(async () => null, 1000);

export const getData = () => {
  return myFunc().then(console.log);
};
```

`utils.ts`:

```js
export const helper = (promiseFunc, time) => (...args) =>
  Promise.race([promiseFunc(...args), new Promise((_, reject) => null)]);
```

`a.spec.ts`:

```js
import * as a from './a';

describe('getData', () => {
  it('myFunc is called', async () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const myFuncMock = jest.spyOn(a, 'myFunc').mockResolvedValueOnce('mocked data');
    await a.getData();
    expect(myFuncMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('mocked data');
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58530865/a.spec.ts (5.431s)
  getData
    ✓ myFunc is called (42ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    mocked data

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.912s, estimated 17s
```